# Java error for drawing progressive line Imagej

Tags: matlab, image-processing, imagej

I am trying to detect cell boundaries(tracking line) but error showing while clicking on progressive line on imageJ can someone please translate the error to me ?I have attached the error here

[refer: printscreen is attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyZcF.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is an IllegalArgumentException, "out of range 2". It means that when you call ImageStack.getProcessor(3), there are not 3 images/slices into your stack.

Exactly the line that generates your error is:

```
if (stack[n-1] instanceof byte[])
```

Use getSize in order to find the number of slices/images present into your stack.

Comment: Thank you. Really appreciated it so much! my dataset in .rec how and what I should do?. I cannot open it in imageJ (fiji). I don't know what I suppose to do. Can you help me on this.

Comment: You can try to import it as an image sequence, or with bio-format (I don't know .rec files).